# Delete user by id on table user can't work

Tags: php, laravel-8

I want to delete my user... by id on table users

Form :

```
<form action="/dashboard/crud/{{ $user->id }}" method="post" class="d-inline">
@csrf
@method('delete')
<button class="badge bg-danger border-0" onclick="return confirm ('Hapus?')"><span data-feather="x-circle"></span></button>
</form>
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('/dashboard/crud', DashboardUserController::class)->middleware('auth');
```

Controller

```
public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        User::destroy($user->id);
        return redirect('/dashboard/crud'); with('success', 'data telah terhapus! ');
    }
```

Did I do something wrong? Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route is not correct

`Route::resource('/dashboard/crud', DashboardUserController::class)->middleware('auth');`

change this to

`Route::post('/dashboard/crud/{user}', DashboardUserController::class)->middleware('auth');`

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#required-parameters

Also delete this line @method('delete')

Comment: Upvote, @method delete its part of form method spoofing and is absolutely valid. please refer to this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: its say Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\DashboardUserDeleteController].

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned process is correct. But in my opinion when you submit a form with POST method you should not send any value via Route/URL.